# Decorator Pattern vs Using super

Tags: java, decorator

I just started learning decorator pattern and I'm confused in when can I use Decorator pattern, or why is it different than just calling super, w/o using a pointer to a super class.

"...is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class."

Isn't it the same as just subclassing or am I missing something?

```
public class Foo {
     protected void doSomething() { }
}


//using decorator pattern
public class Bar extends Foo {
    private foo;
    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        foo.doSomething();
        // extra code
    }
}

//using super

public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Overide
    public void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
        // extra code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that you can create multiple decorators and combine them arbitrarily.

For example, if you have a class `Window` representing a GUI window and want to be able to add horizontal and/or vertical scrollbars, via subclassing you might end up with subclasses
`VerticalScrollingWindow`, `HorizontalScrollingWindow`, `BidirectionalScrollingWindow`, and if you also wanted to add other features, you'd have to combine each feature as another subclass of all of these and the original `Window`.

But with decorators, you avoid this combinatorial explosion.  You need a `VerticalScrollDecorator`, a `HorizontalScrollDecorator` and to get both vertical and horizontal, you just have to decorate twice.  And if you have additional features, you need another decorator per feature.

Comment: Direct, concise and clear answer. thanks!